# Howto use positive feedback validation in Knockout Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I needed some positive feedback on Knockout Validation. Regularly Knockout validation uses the data-bind="validationElement". Somewhat like this:

```
<div data-bind="validationElement: path.to.ko.property">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: path.to.ko.property />
</div>
```

And the validation error can be shown like this, 2 different approaches (see: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings):

```
<div data-bind="validationElement: path.to.ko.property">
     some html/text which will be shown when there is an error.
</div>
<div data-bind="validationMessage: path.to.ko.property">
     some html/text which will be shown when there is an error.
</div>
```

What I want is to have positive feedback as well. So when the field is properly filled (the validation passes) I want to shown positive feedback to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a search I found some code snippets but nothing actually working. So after I while I found my own solution. I'm sharing it here so other people might run into the same problem and want to use the same approach.

You basically need just a extra bindinghandler to make this work. You can use a new bindingHandler but what I did was override and extend the existing one:

```
/**
 * Custom binding for adding an extra success class to the element when success.
 * OVERRIDE NOTE!! use the original for validation first.
 * @type {{update: ko.bindingHandlers.validationElement.update}}
 */
var originalBindingHandlerValidationElement = ko.bindingHandlers.validationElement;

ko.bindingHandlers.validationElement = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // call original method.
        originalBindingHandlerValidationElement.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);

        var obsv = valueAccessor(),
            isModified = false,
            isValid = false,
            isValidating = false;

        if (obsv === null || typeof obsv === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('Cannot bind validationElement to undefined value. data-bind expression: ' +
                element.getAttribute('data-bind'));
        }

        isValid = obsv.isValid && obsv.isValid();
        isModified = obsv.isModified && obsv.isModified();
        isValidating = obsv.isValidating && obsv.isValidating();

        // create an evaluator function that will return something like:
        // css: { validationElement: true }
        var cssSettingsAccessor = function () {
            var css = {};

            css["has-success"] = isValid && (isModified && (obsv()!==null));
            css["has-progress"] = isModified && isValidating;

            return css;
        };

        //add or remove class on the element;
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, cssSettingsAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
    }
};
```

I'm using the original bindingHandler to process the error state which already worked with the Knockout Validation plugin. But added an 'has-success' and 'has-progress' class to the element when it is successful or is processing. The knockout validation init what I'm using is:

```
    ko.validation.init({
        insertMessages: false,
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        errorsAsTitle: false,
        grouping: {
            observable: true,
            deep: true
        }
    }, true);
```

This results in 3 classes which will be placed: has-success, has-error, has-progress.

The next step was for me to have some kind of summarised feedback when multiple fields together are valid or not. So I made another bindingHandler:

```
/**
 * Custom binding for multiple checked properties to validate
 * Usage example: validationElements:[path.to.prop1,path.to.prop2]
 * @type {{update: ko.bindingHandlers.validationElements.update}}
 */
ko.bindingHandlers.validationElements = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,vm) {
        var properties = valueAccessor();
        var allValid = true, allValidating = true, allModified = true, allNull = true;

        for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++) {
            var propModel = properties[i];

            var isModified = propModel.isModified && propModel.isModified(),
                isValid = propModel.isValid && propModel.isValid(),
                isValidating = propModel.isValidating && propModel.isValidating();

            allValid = allValid && isValid;
            allModified = allModified && isModified;
            allValidating = allValidating && isValidating;
            allNull = allNull && (propModel()!==null);
        }

        // create an evaluator function that will return something like:
        // css: { validationElement: true }
        var cssSettingsAccessor = function () {
            var css = {};

            css["has-success"] = allValid;
            css["has-progress"] = allModified && allValidating;
            css["has-error"] = !allValid && allModified;

            return css;
        };

        //add or remove class on the element;
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, cssSettingsAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
    }
};
```

This validation handler can be used like this:

```
<div data-bind="validationElement: path.to.ko.property1">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: path.to.ko.property1" />
</div>
<div data-bind="validationElement: path.to.ko.property2">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: path.to.ko.property2" />
</div>
<div data-bind="validationElements:[path.to.ko.property1, path.to.ko.property2]">
     <i class="fa fa-check is-success"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle is-error"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse is-progress"></i>
</div>
```

After/during validation the validationElements div will become like one of these:
    
         
         
         
    
or
    
         
         
         
    
or

With this approach your are able to give the user positive feedback on validation. With the following css snippet you can nail it.

```
.is-success,
.is-error,
.is-progress {
    display: none;
}
.has-success .is-success {
    color: green;
    display: block;
}
.has-error .is-error {
    color: red;
    display: block;
}
.has-progress .is-progress {
    color: yellow;
    display: block;
}
```

I hope this will help anyone else, since it took me a couple of hours to nail it. I have setup a codepen for this with a minimal working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOBbJG